# Existence of a Spatial Curve with normal vector constant angle to the $z$-Axis?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, integral-equations

Is it possible to find a spatial curve $\alpha(s) = (x(s), y(s), z(s))$ such that the lines containing the normal vector $\hat{n}(s)$ at each point on the curve $\alpha(s)$ intersect the $z$-axis at a constant angle $\theta$?

My attempts:
For any point $(r(s) \cos \phi(s), r(s) \sin \phi(s), h(s))$, the unit normal vector is given by
$$
\hat{n}(s) = (\sin \theta \cos \phi(s), \sin \theta \sin \phi(s), \cos \theta).
$$
The normal curvature vector is defined as
$$
n(s) = \kappa(s) (\sin \theta \cos \phi(s), \sin \theta \sin \phi(s), \cos \theta).
$$
with $\kappa(s)$ the curvature.
Since the derivative of the unit tangent vector $\hat{T}(s)$ with respect to arc length $s$ is equal to the normal curvature vector, we have
$$
\frac{d \hat{T}(s)}{ds} = \kappa(s) {\hat n}(s).
$$
Therefore, the unit tangent vector $\hat{T}(s)$ can be expressed as
$$
\hat{T}(s) = \left(\sin \theta \int_0^s \kappa(s')\cos \phi(s') \, ds', \, \sin \theta \int_0^s \kappa(s')\sin \phi(s') \, ds', \, \cos \theta \int_0^s \kappa(s') \, ds'\right).
$$
Given that $\hat{T}(s)$ is a unit vector, it must satisfy the condition
$$
\sin^2 \theta \left( \left( \int_0^s \kappa(s')\cos \phi(s') \, ds' \right)^2 + \left( \int_0^s \kappa(s')\sin \phi(s') \, ds' \right)^2 \right) + \cos^2 \theta \left( \int_0^s \kappa(s') \, ds' \right)^2 = 1.
$$

Question: How can I find a solution to the above equations?

Comment: The question in the title is different from the question in the first sentence. Which is it?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry for the confusion. It should be the question in the first sentence, since there is limited words in title.

Comment: The easiest answer to your question is: Yes, take any circular helix spiraling around the $z$-axis. In that case the angle is $\pi/2$. Much more common in differential geometry is a generalized helix, where the *tangent* to the curve makes a constant angle with a fixed vector. But this results in the same sort of equation that you have: $(-\kappa\hat T + \tau\hat n)\cdot\hat k = 0$. Where is this question arising?

Comment: @TedShifrin From do carmo Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces, the exercise 1 in chapter 1.5. He came up with an example with $\theta = \pi/2$. I'm curious about a concrete example of general $\theta$

Comment: OK, so I gave you the same example. I would suggest following up on my comments. First, if you take a generalized helix, what happens? There’s a typo in my previous comment. The $\hat n$ should be $\hat b$.